# how to read single column from csv file using python in sikuli

Tags: python, csv

i referred python tutorials, but while coming to this situation I'm not sure the problem is where. Here I'm attaching my snippet code kindly look into once and give me the solution.

Here i want to print single column, please provide me solution
Thank you in advance

```
import csv
Col1 = "ColumnName1"
Col2 = "ColumnName2"
Col3 = "ColumnName3"
mydictionary={Col1:[], Col2:[], Col3:[]}
csvFile = csv.reader(open("D:\\Sikuli\\example1.csv", "rb"))
for row in csvFile:
  mydictionary[Col1].append(row[0])
  mydictionary[Col2].append(row[1])
  mydictionary[Col3].append(row[2])

for row in csvFile:
  col1, col2, col3 = row
  print "%s: %s, %s" % (col1, col2, col3)
```

my csv file is:

```
Presedence,Sno,STP-testcaseno,Test_id,Scenario,Simulator,Comport

0,1,STP-GPSBL-001,SimZen-001,general,SimZen,com1

1,2,STP-GPSBL-002,SimZen-002,general,SimZen,com2

1,3,STP-GPSBL-003,Simplex-003,gpsblhsiura1,Simplex,com1

0,4,STP-GPSBL-004,SimZen-004,gpsblhsiura1,SimZen,com1

1,5,STP-GPSBL-005,Accord-005,general1,Accord,com3

0,6,STP-GPSBL-006,Ifen-006,general1,Ifen,com1
```

Comment: Can you show your csv file and expected output?

Comment: Presedence Sno STP-testcaseno Test_id Scenario Simulator Comport 
0 1 STP-GPSBL-001 SimZen-001 general SimZen com1 
1 2 STP-GPSBL-002 SimZen-002 general SimZen com2 
1 3 STP-GPSBL-003 Simplex-003 gpsblhsiura1 Simplex com1

Comment: above one is csv file and output is not coming and also it doesn't show any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate lines in your csvfile are empty and get translated as `[]`. So you will get a `IndexError: list index out of range` exception when you attempt to index e.g. `row[0]`. Additionally, even if this was resolved, as later you unpack `row` with fewer variables than there are elements in row, you would get a `ValueError: too many values to unpack` exception. This fixes the issues:

```
import csv                                                                                                                
Col1 = "ColumnName1"                                                                                                      
Col2 = "ColumnName2"                                                                                                      
Col3 = "ColumnName3"                                                                                                      
mydictionary={Col1:[], Col2:[], Col3:[]}                                                                                  
csvFile = csv.reader(open("D:\\Sikuli\\example1.csv", "rb"))                                                                          
for row in csvFile:
    if row:                                                                                                       
        mydictionary[Col1].append(row[0])                                                                                 
        mydictionary[Col2].append(row[1])                                                                                 
        mydictionary[Col3].append(row[2])                                                                                 

for k in range(len(mydictionary[Col1])):                                                                                  
  print "%s: %s, %s" % (mydictionary[Col1][k], mydictionary[Col2][k], mydictionary[Col3][k])
```

I would recommend that you use the `with` statement to open your file; and then use `csv`'s `DictReader` class:

```
import csv
Col1='Presedence'
Col2='Sno'
Col3='STP-testcaseno'

with open("D:\\Sikuli\\example1.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    print '{} {} {}'.format(Col1,Col2,Col3)
    for row in reader:
        print '{:<10} {:<}\t{:<}'.format(row[Col1],row[Col2],row[Col3])
```

Output:

```
Presedence Sno STP-testcaseno
0          1    STP-GPSBL-001
1          2    STP-GPSBL-002
1          3    STP-GPSBL-003
0          4    STP-GPSBL-004
1          5    STP-GPSBL-005
0          6    STP-GPSBL-006
```